# How to customize SharePoint 2010 mobile view

Tags: sharepoint-2010, mobile-website, sharepoint-branding

I am stuck on developing a mobile view for my SP2010 publishing portal. It is Internet-facing with custom pages / web parts (e.g. http://server/Pages/customPage.aspx with custom webparts on it). The site has a custom master page.

I am having the following issues with the built-in mobile functionality:

1. The welcome page. Navigating to
   http://server/?Mobile=1 redirects me
   to
   http://server/_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx, which just shows a table of lists / document libraries available. For
   my portal, I want to show a
   dashboard, just like I currently do for the "normal" non-mobile view.
2. Navigating to one of my custom
   pages (e.g.
   http://server/Pages/customPage.aspx?Mobile=1)
   also redirects to
   http://server/_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx.

So in effect there is really no helpful built-in mobile support at all; just the ability to view lists with a mobile device.

---

So I have a number of issues and I'm hoping for some high-level help. My thought is that I should do the following tasks:

1. Create a separate master page for mobile
2. Figure out how to choose this master page based on "is client a mobile device?"
3. Figure out how to prevent the redirection to /_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx

Then I think the mobile site will operate similarly to the normal site.

Am I on the right track?

---

**[Edit]**

With what I have seen from links from @moontear and other research I've done, it sounds like my best option is to just disable built-in SharePoint mobile support, and just do my own conditional rendering based off of `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the extensive MSDN documentation about how to customize Mobile Views:

- [How to: Customize Mobile List View and Form Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861936.aspx)

when you check out that page you can see that you can already change the layouts of the list forms and maybe that is enough for you - but as you said you want a custom "Dashboard", you probably want to look into how the mobile redirection works:

- [Overview of Mobile Pages and the Redirection System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462572.aspx)

You can set which device is treated as mobile device by editing the `compat.browse` file as explained in this post: [SP2010 Branding Tip #6 – Mobile Browsers](http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-6-mobile-browsers.html), this way the device you set is shown your regular Sharepoint page (answering your questions 2/3).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the "_layouts/mobile" folder to e.g. "_layouts/MyCompany/mobile", in webconfig add following appSetting key:

```
<add key="mobile_applicationrootdirectory" value="_layouts/MyCompany/mobile/"/>
```

After that you can add branding, css, etc. to your own mobile folder.
SharePoint is using this by calling SPMobileUtility.GetAppRootDirName()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee553908(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

using powershell

```
 Disable-SPFeature -Identity MBrowserRedirect -Url http://url
```